# db2 reorgchk shows reorg needed immediately after reorg/runstats

Tags: db2, db2-10.5

I did a `reorgchk` and it showed a few indexes needed reorg. So i ran this script:

```
FORCE APPLICATIONS ALL;
CONNECT TO DOMINOS;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSTABLES].[INDTABLES01]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSTABLES REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSPLAN].[INDPLAN03]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSPLAN REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSVIEWDEP].[INDVIEWDEP01]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSVIEWDEP REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSPLANAUTH].[INDPLANAUTH02]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSPLANAUTH REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSVARIABLES].[INDVARIABLES03]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSVARIABLES REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSDATAPARTITIONS].[INDDATAPARTITIONS03]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSDATAPARTITIONS REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSROUTINES].[INDROUTINES10]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSDEPENDENCIES].[INDDEPENDENCIES03]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSDEPENDENCIES REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSCOLUMNS].[INDCOLUMNS02]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS REBUILD;
-- [SYSIBM].[SYSPLANDEP].[INDPLANDEP01]: [*----];
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSPLANDEP REBUILD;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSPLAN WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSVIEWDEP WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSPLANAUTH WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSVARIABLES WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSDATAPARTITIONS WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSDEPENDENCIES WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE SYSIBM.SYSPLANDEP WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
```

Then ran `reorgchk` again, only to find out they still need a reorg (scroll to the right):

```
Index: SYSIBM.INDCOLUMNS02
                               8212    14     0    2     0      15           19            19                822                 822                0  79  97   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDDATAPARTITIONS01
                                214     3     0    2     0     214           34            34                710                 710                0  75 132   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDDATAPARTITIONS03
                                214     3     0    2     0     214           31            31                628                 628                0  75 120   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDDATAPARTITIONS05
                                214     3     0    2     0     214           31            31                628                 628                0  75 120   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDDEPENDENCIES01
                               1691    46     0    3     0    1691           82            82                318                 318                0  75  89  72   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDDEPENDENCIES03
                               1691    12     0    2     0     601           45            45                476                 476                0  78  93   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDPLAN01
                                373     5     0    2     0     373           30            30                516                 516                0  56  98   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDPLAN03
                                373     4     0    2     0     373           24            24                710                 710                0  56 117   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDPLANAUTH01
                                499     8     0    2     0     499           43            43                566                 566                0  67 102   -   0   0 *----
Index: SYSIBM.INDPLANAUTH02
                                499     4     0    2     0     373           22            22                822                 822                0  70 120   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES01
                               1079    15     0    2     0    1079           36            36                566                 566                0  80  96   -   0   0 *----
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES02
                               1079    17     0    2     0    1079           42            42                476                 476                0  67  93   -   0   0 *----
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES03
                               1079    13     0    2     0     957           35            35                516                 516                0  67  97   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES06
                               1079    25     0    2     0    1079           69            69                262                 262                0  67  90   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES08
                               1079     7     0    2     0    1079           13            13                496                 496                0  59 104   -   0   0 *----
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES09
                               1079     3     0    2     0     241            6             6                710                 710                0  80 111   -   0   0 *----
Index: SYSIBM.INDROUTINES10
                               1079    13     0    2     0     957           35            35                516                 516                0  67  97   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDTABLES01
                                709     8     0    2     0     709           26            26                822                 822                0  69 105   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDTABLES05
                                709     9     0    2     0     709           32            32                566                 566                0  69 100   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDVARIABLES03
                                122     2     0    2     0     122           21            21                666                 666                0  58 103   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDVIEWDEP01
                                934    19     0    2     0     934           56            56                476                 476                0  63  91   -   0   0 *----
--
Index: SYSIBM.INDVIEWDEP03
                                934     6     0    2     0     306           38            38                666                 666                0  65 100   -   0   0 *----
--
```

As you can see, they all show an *exceed* (*) in the F4 formula, and according to [the documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001971.html):

> If the results of the calculations for Formula 1, 2 and 3 do not
>   exceed the bounds set by the formula and the results of the
>   calculations for Formula 4, 5 or 6 do exceed the bounds set, then
>   index reorganization is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen as Formula 4 is about the cluster ratio. This is the correlation of the index sequence to the sequence of the data. 
The documentation also states (same page)

> The clustering ratio of an index should be greater than 80 percent.
>   When multiple indexes are defined on one table, some of these indexes
>   have a low cluster ratio. (The index sequence is not the same as the
>   table sequence.) This cannot be avoided. Be sure to specify the most
>   important index when reorganizing the table.

This is why you have multiple formulas to determine the need (and urgency) of a reorg.

Comment: Wow, completely missed the _"When multiple indexes are defined..."_ part...  Thank you!